# Does anyone know if a foreach with a LINQ addition on the data object will enumerate once or multiple times?

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out which of these is more effecient.

The first example using 'continue;' ensures we only enumerate the list once but we include rows we don't have any interest in until after loop has completed.

```
foreach (object in List)
{
  if (object.something == null)
   {
    continue;
   }

  //Do Stuff
}
```

The second example using LINQ on the list object stops the foreach from enumerating undesired rows but I suspect the where check may be doing a full enumeration before the loop even starts, making it less efficient.

```
foreach (object in List.Where(x => x.something != null))
 {
   //Do Stuff
 }
```

I'm not concerned about readability. Only pure speed! Does anyone know for certain which of these will be more efficient (or any other ideas for skipping rows without removing them from the list beforehand)?

Comment: They are *functionally* equivalent, but generally an iteration with an `if` check may perform better. It's best to measure if you're not sure.

Comment: Then measure it.

Comment: Any other ideas to check before I start setting up some measurements?

Comment: Linq has optimizing for different List Types in different versions of the framework. So no whats best in your environment needs to be measured. And if you change something measure again if performance is that relevant.

Comment: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).  There are too many unknowns for us to make guesses.  Particularly regarding the (unspecified) underlying data for `List`, in which a `.Where()` expression could be trivial or costly and we can't know.

Comment: Interesting guys! I didn't know regards the optimization of LINQ differences in different frameworks. I'll keep in mind this will basically always be a "test it" scenario with no specific answer. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: The difference is going to be very small: the LINQ version is essentially doing the same thing except with `Func` lambdas

Answer (score 1):

This has basically been answered in the comments - if performance matters to you then you need to compare your two implementations with as close to a real scenario as possible.

I think it's worth explicitly answering your concern that "the where check may be doing a full enumeration before the loop even starts, making it less efficient" - this is unfounded.

The `Where` method returns an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is your class. This type contains the instructions on how to perform the query, but does not actually perform the query until it is enumerated, known as [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries#deferred-execution). The query is then performed iteratively on each element in turn, as it is enumerated. In your case, the `foreach` will perform the enumeration by:

1. requesting each element from the list
2. filtering the element according to the `Where` expression
3. EITHER: skipping the element
4. OR: executing the code inside the loop for the element

Contrast this with `List.Where(...).ToList()` which would, as you say, do the full enumeration before the loop even starts.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I would replace the second "applying the query" with "applying the `Where` test"... "skipping the element". With a long sentence with so many possible antecedents, I don't think indefinite articles add clarity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply was very helpful. The source of this thought was a discussion that came from peer reviewing a colleagues work. You're going to make half my team happy and half my team grumbly with this outcome! :D (and thanks to those who took the time to reply in comments to!!)

Comment: Glad it was helpful :D Please consider accepting it as the answer if it solved your problem.